# ldap and jwt together in one laravel 5.3 application

Tags: laravel, authentication, ldap, jwt

My requirement is , set of users needed to be request for one service like file upload through restapi ,which I have implemented JWT. and need a web interface to see all downloads , and this web interface should be authenticated by LDAP. I have independently integrated ldap . While I try to integrate ldap and jwt in single app. my jwt(jason web tokens) token based authentication fails. My config/auth.php has

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'adldap',// Was 'eloquent'.
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
```

will work for ldap( ), and 
    enter jwt is working  code here
    'providers' => [
            'users' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\User::class,
            ],
    how to integrate both in single application ?

Comment: I found a solution using https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth

Comment: care to share how you implement the multi-auth with ldap and jwt auth?